# Why is the helmholtz free energy minimized?

Tags: thermodynamics, potential, equilibrium

I don't quite understand the [principle of minimum energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_minimum_energy) despite having read the derivation on Wikipedia.

I think I got lost when the free energy was defined as $A= \max_S{\left(U-TS\right)}$, because I don't know why is the max there.

Comment: The wikipedia page has $\max_S$, not the maximum of the expression.

Comment: @Quantumness I know, but I still don't even know what's that and why is that.

Comment: It is referring to maximum entropy, the second law of thermodynamics.

Comment: @Quantumness I still don't get the derivation :(

Comment: Could you refer to the specific aspect where you are confused? I'm not sure I understand what you are looking for.

Comment: @Quantumness Why does it define $A$ as $A=\max_S(U-TS)$? We were never applying the $\max_S(.)$ on it during the classes.

Comment: It may help to read up on the [Legendre transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation).

Comment: That is not the correct definition of the Helmholtz free energy.  The correct definition is simply $A=U-TS$ (without the max).  At thermodynamic equilibrium in a *closed constant=volume system held in contact with a constant temperature reservoir*, the Helmholtz free energy is minimum.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I know the legendre transform. But I don't know what does the $\max_S$ "do there".

Comment: @ChesterMiller Yes, I know. But I don't know why did they but it there, or what does it do. I do also know that the free enery has it's minimum at equilibrium if $T=const$, but I don't know why.

Comment: The derivation to show that Helmholtz free energy is minimum at equilibrium (under those constraints) is presented in detail and precision in Denbigh, Principles of Chemical Equilibrium.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an alternative derivation to show that Helmholtz energy will be minimized.

Consider the fact that by the second law of thermodynamics, the total entropy $S$ of the universe must increase. That is, the sum of all entropies has the relationship

$$ dS_{\rm universe}  = dS_{\rm sys} + dS_{\rm surr} \geq 0,$$

where 'sys' and 'surr' represent ours system and surrounds respectively. Hold this result for the moment. Recall the thermodynamic identity $dU = TdS-PdV+\mu dN$, and recognize that for constant volume and number of particles,

$$ dS_{\rm surr} = \frac{dU_{\rm surr}}{T} = - \frac{dU_{\rm sys}}{T}. $$

Note that the last equality comes from the first law: energy is conserved, so $dU_{\rm surr} = -dU_{\rm sys}$. Then, plugging this into our earlier result and multiplying by $T$, we have

$$ dS_{\rm universe} = dS_{\rm sys} + dS_{\rm surr} = dS_{\rm sys} - \frac{dU_{\rm sys}}{T}$$
$$ \rightarrow TdS_{\rm universe} = TdS_{\rm sys} - dU_{\rm sys}.$$

Now the proper definition for Helmholtz free energy is $F = U - TS$, so for constant temperature, $dF = dU - TdS = -(TdS-dU)$. We can plug this into our last result as

$$ T dS_{\rm universe} = - dF_{\rm sys} $$

and finally

$$ dS_{\rm universe} = - \frac{dF_{\rm sys}}{T}.$$

Note that in order to maximize the entropy in the universe, you have make the Helmholtz free energy as negative as possible (negative, but large magnitude).